# respondsToSelector - not working

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uinavigationbar, ios7, respondstoselector

I've read through like 10 posts, but haven't found what's wrong with my implementation.

This app was written in iOS 6 but updated to iOS7, so I want to offer support for both iOS6 and iOS7. But if I run an iOS7-only method on an iOS6 device, it breaks. 
So I thought of adding respondsToSelector, to check it has iOS7 on it, but for some reason, the if always returns false.

AppDelegate.m:

```
if ([[UINavigationBar appearance] respondsToSelector:@selector(shadowImage)])

if ([[UINavigationBar appearance] respondsToSelector:@selector(setShadowImage:)])
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Edit: I've tried with deployment target set to both iOS6 and iOS7, both cases return false.

Edit2: If I remove the if statement and call the method, it works as intended in iOS7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of querying `[UINavigationBar appearance]` for the selector, just

```
[UINavigationBar instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(shadowImage)]
```

an alternative solution may be checking the iOS version

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"7.0" options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
    NSLog(@"iOS >= 7.0");
```

Comment: It works, could you explain why I need to use instacesRespondToSelector instead of respondsToSelector? I'd like to actually know why I use something :)

Comment: I prefer the responds to selector method, lot more dynamic.

Comment: It's because of `appearance` proxy approach. You can find more info [there](http://nshipster.com/uiappearance/)

Comment: Also thank you for showing me the systemVersion method, I needed it to set the UINavigationBar size based on it.