# If my app uses ios7 new feature, can it be installed in iOS 6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, ios7

In my app, I want to use iOS 7 new feature: silent remote notifications. Also, I have to insure it can be installed and run rightly in iOS 6. Whether the two scenes conflict?

I have tried this:

```
#ifdef IOS7_OR_LATER
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void(^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
   ...
}
#endif
```

Does this works in iOS 6? Cause I don't have a iOS 6 device, so I hope some experienced man could give me some advice.
Thanks for any help you can give. ^_^

Comment: watch iOS 7 Tech Talk Session called "Integrating iOS 7 System Technologies"

Comment: you don't need an iOS 6 device to test this, use the simulator .....

Comment: but simulator can not receive push notifications~

Comment: When you submit to the App Store, you send a single binary to be run on all devices.  Any #ifdef statement will be evaluated at compile time, and the result will be baked into your binary.  So this approach will NOT change how your app runs on different devices.

Comment: @NealEhardt Sorry, I have some trouble to understand "the result will be baked into your binary".You mean the #ifdef I used can't help me to achieve my goal?

Comment: #ifdef is a [preprocessor directive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor).  It is evaluated and discarded before the app leaves your computer, to your test device or to the App Store for others to download.  It is not suitable for your goal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the recent Apple Tech Talks, there are 4 proper ways to do this:

1. **use [`respondsToSelector`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/respondsToSelector%3a)**
   (if the method exists in iOS7 but not in iOS6)
2. **use `&IOS7OnlyConstant != nil`**
   (if the selector would be recognized by iOS6, but not the particular constant)
3. **use [Class Clusters](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/ClassCluster.html)**
   (using *private subclasses* for iOS6 and iOS7)
4. **use [Categories](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Category.html)**
   (to override and rename common methods. You then do the distinction in the method implementation.)

Comment: Hi,Mundi. I thought about the 4 ways you supported.In my case, the method application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: is invoked by the system, I cannot manually invoke this method explicitly, so in my opinion , the first way is not suitable for me, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953705/respondstoselector-not-working) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18303786/writing-ios7-code-that-compiles-against-ios-6-base-sdk) topic can help you. Including the usage of "respondsToSelector" for differentiating methods regarding iOS version.

Comment: I have also defined this:#define IOS7_OR_LATER ( [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"7.0"] != NSOrderedAscending )

Comment: - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void(^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler        , this is a delegate method when app received remote push notifications, how can I use "respondsToSelector"?I am a little confused~

Comment: @SomnusLee This method has been particularly snubbed at by Apple in the recent Tech Talks. They recommend to check `NSFoundationVersionNumber` against e.g. `NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1`.

Comment: @Mundi Hi,Mundi. You mean "[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] " this method has been snubbed？

Comment: @SomnusLee Yes, especially the `compare` bit. See https://developer.apple.com/tech-talks/videos/, "Architecting Modern Apps, Part 2".